# Handling action parameter in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

In template:

```
<button {{action someAction someParameter}}>Some Action</button>
```

In controller:

```
someAction: function (e, someParameter) {
    console.log(e, someParameter);
}
```

`someParameter` is undefined as well as `e` where I excepted to be event object.

How to pass parameter to action? If not possible does it mean I need to create `Ember.View` to handle action with parameter?

Comment: could you create a fiddle/bin with your code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only problem I see in your code is that **the event object is not passed to the function in the controller when using the {{action}} helper**. Regardless of that, your code should log the value of `someParameter` to the console. If you are getting two `undefined` maybe `someParameter` is **not within the context of the template**, or it is `undefined`.

Make sure `someParameter` is there and holds the correct value, for example:

Template:

```
<button {{action someAction someParameter}}>Some Action (param: {{someParameter}} )  </button>
```

If the value doesn't show up, try `view.someParameter` depending on how you are rendering the template, if you show your code we might be able to help you more.

On the controller:

```
someAction: function (someParameter) {
  console.log(someParameter);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! someParameter was undefined indeed. The only remaining question is how to get access to the `event` object in _controller_? I see example here http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html but they are using _View_. I have only **template** and **controller**, mine template is not reusable so I don't want to create view however I want to have access to `event` object.

Comment: You cannot use the event object with the {{action}} helper. Is there a reason you want to do it? What is the requirement?

Comment: How would that work with a component? For ex. {{my-component action="myHandler" someParams}}